# How to create a Proxy Server using Swift Perfect Framework?

Tags: swift, proxy, httprequest, perfect

I want to use Swift Perfect Framework to make a proxy server. 
My idea is following:

1. get the request's url ,header.etc informations.
2. use the informations to create new request.
3. get response from the new request.and use the response's information to set the origin request's response.

My Question is how can I make a new request using Swift Perfect Framework? Or I need to use other Framework.

Answer (score 1):

you can use CURLRequest of Perfect-CURL to perform the actual request and send it back to the response once received something.